# How do i install real linux on a chromebook?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chromebook

So I am buying my new Chromebook, and since chromeOS is closed source I want to install Linux. I found online guides to it, but they were all for Installing the Linux (Beta) Feature AKA Crostini on it, which Is a built in feature. I actually want to remove chromeOS and install Linux, specifically ubuntu. My Chromebook Is: `Acer 315 Celeron N4000 4GB Ram, 32GB eMMC (CB315-3H-C2C3)`. I originally wanted to install Windows, but it was only available on the CB315-2H Model, and I had the CB315-3H Model. The chromebook is not compatible with MrChromeBox's Custom UEFI Bios/FWScript.

Comment: Hi Karim and welcome to Superuser! Glad to see that you've started the research and found Crostini, but when I google "install linux on chromebook" the [first hit](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-install-linux-on-your-chromebook) explains how you can dual boot. Could you please extend your research (also on this site: you caa look at the related questions on the right) and edit your question?

Comment: Also, if you haven't bought the Chromebook yet and you already know that you want linux and not ChromeOS, why not choose a "regular" laptop?

Comment: I bought a chromebook for Monetary reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flash a firmware update to make your Chromebook look like a regular computer to the Linux installer.

This site has the firmware updater you need:  https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript

Comment: It is not compatible with that script i explain that in the question

Comment: Apologies for not reading carefully.  Since you can't update the firmware your only choice is to pull the Chromebook in developer mode and setup Crouton.  This is not a full install but lets you run Linux within ChromeOS.